# Traverse each word in a paragraph VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to Traverse each word in a paragraph, I write my code:

```
sub search_word_in_paragraph()
With selection.Find
            .Text = "[A-Za-z]{2,}"
            .MatchWildcards = True
            Do
                .Execute
                If .Found Then

                            If selection.Range.Text = "and" Then
                                selection.Range.Case = wdLowerCase
                                Exit For
                            End If

                End If
            Loop Until selection.Range.Previous <> " "
            selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord
            selection.HomeKey unit:=wdLine
        End With
end sub
```

but, i feel can more Concise, are there any other better ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `For...Each` to traverse through words in a paragraph. Below is a sample.

```
Sub TraverseWords()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
For Each wrd In rng.Words
    If Trim(wrd) = "and" Then
        wrd.Case = wdLowerCase
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I want

Comment: but why `For each word in rng.words` is incorrect,  What is the difference between word and wrd

Comment: `Word` refers to the `Word Application`, so you can't use it.